# Creating a tablespace in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, tablespace, chown

I'm trying to create a tablespace in postgres, but I'm getting ownership problems. The command I'm using is:

```
CREATE TABLESPACE magdat OWNER maggie LOCATION '/home/john/BSTablespace'
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR:  could not set permissions on directory "/home/john/BSTablespace": Operation not permitted
```

The folder belongs to postgres:postgres, I've tried changing it to maggie, but if I go :

```
chown maggie:postgres /home/john/BSTablespace
```

I get:

```
chown: invalid user: `maggie:postgres'
```

How come the user does not exist? If I list the users inside of postgres it does come up. Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I would hazard a guess that the problem lies in the permissions of the parent directory "/home/john". Your home directory is probably setup so that only your user has access (i.e chmod 700) to it (it's a good thing for your home directory to be chmod 700, don't change it).

Doing something like:

```
mkdir /BSTablespace
chown postgres:postgres /BSTablespace
```

and then

```
CREATE TABLESPACE magdat OWNER maggie LOCATION '/BSTablespace';
```

should work fine.

Regarding the user maggie: database users are not the same as OS users. That isn't to say that you couldn't have a user in both places named maggie-- but you would need to create the user in both the database and the OS for that to happen.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. Put it in root and there was no problem.

Comment: @gsiems update your answer, chown postgres:postgres /Directory.

Comment: How do you do this for files on a separate drive/partition? I've been trying to reference a '/media/username/drive_name/pg_data' directory, whose permissions are set with a similar `chown` command and parent directory whose permissions are set to 700 (with a separate user). I am getting the same permissions error as the original post, though.

Comment: @MaxCandocia have solved the problem?

Answer (score 2):

When you install Postgres on a Mac, and are trying to use `PgAdmin` to create your databases, tablespaces, etc. You need to know that the `PgAdmin Utility` is running under the `postgres` account that it created when you installed the postgres database and the utilities.

The `postgres account` is part of the `_postgres` group

( `dscacheutil -q group|grep -i postgres` command will list the group associated with the `postgres` account)

The best practice would be to create a new directory under root(`/`) for housing the tablespaces,(let us call it `/postgresdata` then make `postgres:_postgres` the owners of that directory, using the command below)

`sudo chown postgres:_postgres /postgresdata`

This should do it for you.
You could then create a subdirectory under `/postgresdata` for each unique table space

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with this solution. Think about it. Why do you want to create a new tablespace? Most people do it for either space limitations or performance. In both cases, that means placing each tablespace on a different drive. So, archive data goes on the slower hard-drive, while actively used data does on the SSD.

Assume your OS is on the SSD and you have mounted your slower spin up hard drive as /media/slowdrive. The same dilemma would occur if the reverse, where the spinup is the OS and SSD is the mounted.

Your solution would place the new tablespace at /newtablespace.

Do you see the problem? ... /newtablespace is on the SSD, which does not have the capacity to hold both the archival and active data. If it did, we would not be creating a new tablespace in the first place.

So, how do we solve this issue when our newtablespace is mounted at /media/slowdrive/newtablespace? In my case, the slowdrive (spinup HD) is mounted as root:root for security purposes, although I am not entirely sure about why. What you are suggesting is that I have to chage the mount of my secondary drive to postgres:postgres in addition to having the newtablespace directory as postgres:postgres. That makes no sense, especially since I use this drive for many other reasons than just a postgres tablesapce.

Joe